# I want to add onclicklistener on nested recycleView and open new activity with passing value

Tags: android, onclicklistener, nestedrecyclerview

I have nested RecyclerView with two Adapters(ItemAdapterand and SubItemAdapter), I want to add onclicklistener on nested recycleView and open new activity with passing the value.[text](https://github.com/iamkc07/StudyNShort1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.